# how to determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to determine a function that for a given a sequence of integers (as an array) and that can determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

the arrays can be in range

`2 ≤ sequence.length ≤ 10^5,
-10^5 ≤ sequence[i] ≤ 10^5`

for example:

`[1, 3, 2, 1]` we can not drop any one number in order to get increasing sequence, so the function should return `False`. And True for `[0, -2, 5,  6]`, `[1, 1]`, `[1, 3, 2]`.

I wanted to write function that deletes one number from the list and examines whether the sequence is increasing. If for all iterations we become `False` than the function should return `False`.

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    def order(A):
        n = len(A)
        for i in range(n):
           if A[i] >= A[i+1]:
              result = True
        else:
              result = False            
    for i in range(len(s0)-1):
        s_i = list(sequence)
        s_i.remove(s_i.index(s_i[i]))
           if order(s_i) == True:
    return True
```

But I have got a mistake:

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

What is the reason? How I can finish my code?

Comment: `list.remove()` removes the (first) *element* from the list. You're giving it the *index* of the element instead.

Comment: For what it's worth: numpy has a `diff` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    for i in range(len(sequence)-1):
        s_i = list(sequence)

        # Remove the item by index
        del s_i[i]

        if order(s_i) == True:
            return True

    # Need to return false at the end if we never find a solution
    return False

# You should have tested this function separately first.
# It did not work, so obviously almostIncreasingSequence wouldn't work.
def order(A):
    n = len(A)

    # Should have been n-1, not n, because you compare against n+1
    # which doesn't exist when you hit the tail
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if A[i] > A[i + 1]:
            # Need to actually return the value, not just set it to a variable
            return False
    # Only tell us it's in order if ALL the values don't fail
    return True

print almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2])
```

Comment: AFAICT, this method is much slower (`O(n**2)`) than the other answer (`O(n)`).

Comment: Correct, but OP asked how to fix his code, not how best to accomplish the task. The question also suggests that the OP is rather new to coding, and simplicity should be favored over efficiency at this stage. They're clearly just learning programming, not computer science.

Comment: I get your point. Answers are written for the community, not only for the OP, though. Next time, you could consider adding a small comment about efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

as mentioned in the comments, you can use the [numpy.diff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) for this, and thus avoiding the need to check every combination of removing 1 element from the list

```
import numpy

def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    diff = numpy.diff(sequence) < 1
    return diff.sum() < 2
```

here first we get the difference between adjacent elements, then we ask where those differences are less than 1 and count it, and depending on the amount we get our answer.

Without numpy, we can use a similar technique

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a,b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b,None)
    return zip(a,b) # use itertools.izip in python 2

def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    return sum( a>=b for a,b in pairwise(sequence)) < 2
```

and this one have the advantage that use less memory than the numpy version

And here are some test for it

```
assert almostIncreasingSequence([0, -2, 5,  6])
assert almostIncreasingSequence([1,1])
assert almostIncreasingSequence([1,3,2])
assert almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,3,0])
assert almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,3,0,10])
assert almostIncreasingSequence([10,1,2,3,4])
assert almostIncreasingSequence([1,10,2,3,4])
assert not almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,3,0,0])
assert not almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,0,3,0,10])
assert not almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,0,3,10,0])
assert not almostIncreasingSequence([1,2,3,0,10,0])
assert not almostIncreasingSequence([10,1,2,3,10,0])
assert not almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1])
```

in response to the comments, here is an early stop version

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    diff = 0
    for a,b in pairwise(sequence):
        if a>=b:
            diff += 1
            if diff >= 2:
                return False
    return diff < 2
```

and an accompanying test

```
assert not almostIncreasingSequence(itertools.chain([1, 3, 2, 1],range(10**100))) # use xrange with python 2
```

which will take ages with any of the other version